# How to align a website to the center of the screen top/bottom and right/left?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I want to have the effect like dropbox:https://www.dropbox.com/ where my website is centered in the exact middle of the page.

Comment: I have been able to center the left and right with a `div` with the attributes of `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;`. I want the top and bottom to be aligned too.

Comment: I achieve this on my own site: www.frende.me. It's actually quite a pain to do it dynamically.

Comment: How did you do it? Could you post anything at all?

Comment: use `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieving this effect is way more complicated than it should be. Here's a bare-bones working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JakobJingleheimer/UEsYM/

```
html, body { height: 100%; } // needed for vertical centre

html { width: 100%; } // needed for horizontal centre

body {
    display: table; // needed for vertical centre
    margin: 0 auto; // needed for horizontal centre
    width: 50%; // needed for horizontal centre
}

.main-container {
    background-color: #eee;
    display: table-cell; // needed for vertical centre
    height: 100%; // needed for vertical centre
    // overflow: auto; // <- probably a good idea
    vertical-align: middle; // needed for vertical centre
    width: 100%; // needed for horizontal centre
}

.container {
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

[image: screenshot from JSFiddle example]

Comment: It does not center it on the page just in the corner

Comment: My screenshot says otherwise. What browser are you using? (I'm pretty sure this even works in ancient versions of IE).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this:

[image: How it looks]

Here are different methods, with the pros/cons of each one, for centering a page vertically. Choose which one you prefer:

> http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

EDIT. As suggested, I will proceed to explain one of the methods. It only works if you already know the height/width of the element to center (the link includes more methods). Assuming all your content is within `<body>`, and that your content is 900px x 600px, you can do in your css:

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  }
body {
  width: 900px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -300px; /* Half of the height of your body */
  }
```

However, this falls short for dynamically generated content, since you don't know the height of it. I've used it succesfully on log-in box pop-up and settings pop-up.

Another method I've used in the past for the whole page is the Method 1 from the link. It makes a set of divs to behave as a table, which can vertical-align to the middle.

Comment: An answer consisting of one or more URLs [is not helpful to other users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Please edit your post so that it contains enough information to answer the question and add URLs for further reading only.

Comment: The problem is that a link can be CC-wiki. However, if I copy the text it'd be a violation of that site's copyright, and writing the methods perfectly explained there again would be simply put a waste of time. I am explaining one method and commenting on other method.

Comment: I appreciate it's a difficult position. I think you have now struck the correct balance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align it vertically center, please check this web page: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width and height of your page
then wrap your contents in following div css

```
.center
{
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin-left: -(yourPageWidth/2);
margin-top: -(YourPageHeight/2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your topmost div give **margin:0 auto 0 auto;** Also define some width to that div.

Answer (score 0):

First create a main container of the desired width and then put all your code inside the main container. For Eg.

```
<body>
   <div id="container">
     ......... your code

   </div>
</body>
```

And in the css

```
#container{
  width: 700px ;
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
}
```

You can change the width as per your needs

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
     ......... your code

   </div>
</body>

#container{
  width: 700px ;
  margin:0 auto ;
  padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

html

```
<span id="forceValign"></span><!--
--><div id="centerMiddleWrap">
  <div id="centered">Hello this is some text. Hello this is some text. Hello this is some text.</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    background: #eee;
 }
 body {
   margin: 0;
   height: 100%;
   /*important*/
   text-align: center;
 }
 #centerMiddleWrap {
  /*important*/
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
 }
 #forceValign {
   /*important*/
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
 }
#centered {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 34px;
    padding: 15px;
    max-width: 50%;
    /*important*/
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Here is an demo](http://codepen.io/mrsmee89/full/oDGCx)

Answer (score -1):

Wrap a div and define its width, use `margin:0 auto` for centering the div.

You can check a site's CSS by using *Firebug* or *browser extensions*.

Comment: I can center it in the middle but not the FULL middle of the page. Take a look at the link in the original question